# Практика в Scala

Tags: scala

Подскажите, есть ли ресурсы, где можно попрактиковаться в написании кода на Scala? Можно просто сборники задач по основному функционалу языка. Желательно, чтобы было освещено побольше проблем, связанных с функциональным программированием. Ссылки на ресурсы по спортивному программированию, где принимают решения на Scala, тоже категорически приветствуются.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Для разгона

- [99 задачек для Scala](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) - подборка
  99 небольших упражнений на выработку
  идиоматического стиля написания кода,
  знакомства с классами и методами
  стандартной библиотеки, короче, чтобы
  освоиться со Scala.
- [Упражнения для начинающих
  программистов на Scala](http://blog.tmorris.net/scala-exercises-for-beginners/) от
  знаковой фигуры в мире
  функционального программирования,
  Тони Морриса. Если не знаете, кто это
  такой - марш читать рассылки
  scala-user и scala-debate. :)
- [20 упражнений умеренной сложности
  для Scala](http://dibblego.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/20-intermediate-scala-exercises/) от все того же Тони
  Морриса.
- [CodeCata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/) - сборник практических,
  приближенных к реальности, задач по
  программированию, часто с перечнем
  тестовых данных. Не привязаны к
  конкретному языку, хотя часто для
  демонстрации используется Ruby. В
  комментариях пишут решения на самых
  разных языках, от C/C++ до Lisp.

### Для обретения уверенности

- [Codechef](http://www.codechef.com) - отличный учебный и олимпиадный ресурс с кучей задач самого различного толка, автоматической валидацией решений (поддерживаются Scala и Haskell), и прочими вкусностями.
- [Sphere Online Judge](http://www.spoj.pl/) - аналогичная площадка, с бОльшим уклоном на соревновательную составляющую. Поддерживает Scala и Haskell.
- [Список задачек](http://www.streamtech.nl/site/problem+set), которые в небезызвестной в узких гругах нидерландской компании Streamtech предлагают на собеседованиях при приеме на работу.
- [Programming Praxis](http://programmingpraxis.com/) изначально вышел из сообщества программистов на языке Scheme, но сейчас на ресурсе активно решают задачи на самых различных языках. Особый упор делается на функциональное программирование.

### Для постижения дзена

Все, что перечислено выше - херня. В определенном смысле, конечно :). Эти ресурсы помогут научиться алгоритмическому мышлению, различным алгоритмам, процедурному программированию, может быть, даже, объектно-ориентированному, хотя это вряд ли. Но это не научит вас функциональному программированию (ФП) - ни на йоту. До того, как взяться за Scala, я изучал много языков, в разной мере, конечно: Pascal, C/C++, Perl, Python, Smalltalk, Scheme. И даже начатки функционального программирования по небезызвестному SICP. Но приходится признать: все это мне мало помогло схватить суть функционального программирования. Ну разве что чуть-чуть. Методология ФП мне понравилась сразу, но до последнего я плевался: "Дурацкий Haskell со своим уродливым синтаксисом, идиотской математической терминологией для профессоров - к черту!". И лишь однажды, уже после того, как я начал заниматься Scala, от делать нечего я открыл главу из Душкина, посвященную спискам и еще чему-то там, и... что-то сдвинулось в моей голове - прочитав всю главу с увлечением, я понял, что настало, наконец, время для Haskell. И приходится признать: одни лишь первые 5 глав "Real World Haskell" дали мне НАМНОГО больше, чем все те многочисленные книги по языкам, которые я изучал до этого. Haskell - это реально посвящение в дзен ФП. Без него это ОЧЕНЬ и ОЧЕНЬ трудно сделать, хотя, возможно, вы и будете думать что все знаете и понимаете. Проверено на собственном опыте. Возможно, ваш путь будет более успешен, но вы можете не повторять моих ошибок, и на досуге изучать Haskell. Но это уже другая история :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый ответ! Базовые основы ФП у меня есть: был курс в университете, плюс на досуге почитывал ["Практику функционального программирования"](http://www.fprog.ru/). Я пока далеко не стремлюсь постичь дзен ФП, просто захотелось себя попробовать в новой области :) Scala выбрал из-за того, что больше 4 лет программирую на Java и подумал, что переход будет более плавным, чем, например, на Haskell или Erlang, которые мне показались немного академичными. И еще раз спасибо за ссылки!

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Насчет дзена, это правильно: дзен сам вас найдет, когда придет тому время, просто помните, что придет он из области Хаскеля, а не откуда то еще :) А что касается перехода на Scala - все верно, с бэкграундом из Java это сделать более-менее легко. Придется, правда, первое время потрах... помучиться со средами разработки, инструментами для сборки (simple-build-tool) и проч. В остальном дело техники.

Comment: Для постижения дзена советую ещё "Functional Programming in Scala"

Answer (score 2):

Очень скоро начнется [онлайн курс от создателя языка](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) -- Мартина Одерски, насколько мне известно там будут не только видео лекции но и задачки, поэтому очень рекомендую хотя бы взглянуть на него.